# solr two or more independent checkboxes

Tags: faceted-search

i have a requirement where i have to display the two check boxes filters which are totally independent meaning that only a result of single filter is possible at a time.However When i check one of the check box,the other should still display its count,so i can see its count even though i dint check it.I have tried it using the tag and exclude keywords but it seems to work for values of a single filter.how can i get the check boxes to work one at a time,but still show the count of the other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at solving the same problem at the moment and I believe you will find the information under [Multi-Select Faceting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Multi-Select_Faceting_and_LocalParams) in the SOLR manual.